# How to split a string in a listbox and showing it in another listbox

Tags: c#

I opened a text file and showed it in a listbox (lstArchivo) every string is divided by a semi colon (;) i'm trying to split every string in that listbox (lstArchivo) that has the semicolon. The problem i'm having is that when i display the new splitted list in listbox1 the output i get is String[] Array in every item. Is it better to split every string reading from textfile directly or reading from listbox?

```
 string[] strFields;
        string strLine;
        char[] charDelimiter = { ';' };

        foreach(string item in lstArchivo.Items)
        {
            strLine = lstArchivo.Items.ToString();
            strFields = strLine.Split(charDelimiter);
            listBox1.Items.Add(strFields);
        }
```

this is the code i have

Comment: Split() produces an array.  Arrays display as the TYPE when added to the ListBox.  Did you perhaps want to display a particular "column" from that array in the other ListBox?

Comment: Yes! @Idle_Mind

Comment: ...and what "column" would that be?  1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc....

Comment: EN-ENFE-BEN;jeniffer.martinez this are the strings in the text file, I want to show EN-ENFE-BEN. so it would be strFields[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code like this:

```
char[] charDelimiter = { ';' };
foreach(string item in lstArchivo.Items)
{
    strFields = item.Split(charDelimiter);
    listBox1.Items.Add(strFields[0]);
}
```

Note that we are splitting on "item" from your `foreach` loop.